# Understanding session save path as no value and security

Tags: php, security, session, session-variables

I only use sessions to store variables and was hoping to ensure that the session save path could not be tampered with by any of the users. So I went to check my phpinfo and found that the session save path was set to no value. Is this normal for users who only use sessions for variables? Do I have anything to worry about if the sessions save path is set to no value?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The default value for the [`session.save_path`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path) setting is `""` (empty string), which defaults to `/tmp`.

From a "working" standpoint, there is no need to worry that it's set to no value (as that's the default); however, from a security standpoint there is.

Warning from the manual:

> If you leave this set to a world-readable directory, such as /tmp (the
>   default), other users on the server may be able to hijack sessions by
>   getting the list of files in that directory.

Comment: So then I should set the session save path to an obscure file name and that will solve the security issue?

Comment: Notice that it says other users on the **server**, that is, other users with server access. If you don't explicitly give your users server access there is not much to worry about from a security stand point because the default `tmp` folder is not publically reachable via http requests.

Comment: @Mahn Correct - except any user that can, for any reason, gain access to execute PHP will have access to the `/tmp` folder as well. This could be a fellow web-developer, or someone malicious who found a hole. Turning a blind eye because it *seems* too hard to worry about is hardly a good security standard.

Comment: @newfurniturey I think you would have bigger problems to worry about if any user for any reason could gain access to execute PHP on your machine.

Comment: @jason328 Obscurity is not entirely necessary, but definitely somewhere outside of the `/tmp` folder (or, at least make it a sub-folder such as `/tmp/sessions/` and to make the directory only readable by one user). The key is to set a custom save-path for every application you're running.

Comment: @Mahn Quite true, but the ability to stealth-fully hijack a session on an e-commerce website would be far more appealing than using the server in a botnet (among other misc. things). This conversation branch could go on for days, but in the end - security is security and you shouldn't brush things under the carpet.

Comment: So create the folder then set session save path php function before session start...

Comment: @jason328 Correct. If you have multiple websites running, perhaps try creating the directory inside each specific website (like `/home/example.com/session`) and have an include in the header of every page that uses the sessions that calls `session_save_path('/home/example.com/session');`. Doing this should also keep file/folder permissions manageable.

Comment: @newfurniturey Old post, but just a thought: Certain systems such as Cloudlinux "jail" the /tmp for you already under each account, so no `session_save_path` mitigations are needed "in-app". Example location:  `/home/someaccount/.cagefs/tmp/`

Answer (score 0):

you can set save_path by create/edit .htaccess by this codes:

```
php_value session.save_path /mnt/stor1-wc1-dfw1/123456/www.domain.com/web/sessions
php_value session.save_handler files
```

for more details visit this site:[PHP Sessions State Servers on Cloud Sites And How To Fix Non Working PHP Sessions](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/php-sessions-state-servers-on-cloud-sites-and-how-to-fix-non-working-php-sessions/)